# Сумма цифр в числе

Tags: javascript

```js
let num = prompt('Введите число')

for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  x = Number(num[i]) + Number(num[i + 1])
  alert(`Сумма всех цифр числа: ${x}`)
}
```

Вот мои догадки, но в моем случае когда все цифры числа одинаковы,суммируются первые две цифры

Comment: "когда все цифры числа одинаковы,суммируются первые две цифры" - не может быть

Comment: почему не может быть? когда я ввожу число 111 - мне выводит цифру 2, хотя сумма 3

Comment: А когда вводите "456"? При чем здесь одинаковость цифр?

Comment: Действительно одинаковость ни причем, тоже выводит 9, хотя сумма 15

Comment: "выводит 9" - и все? Больше ничего не выводит?

Comment: И все, больше ничего

Comment: не может быть. Нажмите на кнопку "Выполнить код" в вопросе.

Comment: 9,11,NaN. Не заметил изначально

Comment: Вы что, не видите, что Вы выводите суммы двух соседних цифр?

Comment: не догадываюсь как изменить так, чтобы суммировалось все

Answer (score 3):

```js
function fSumAllDigits(n) {
  return [...n.toString()].reduce((acc, el) => acc + parseInt(el), 0);
}
console.log( fSumAllDigits(111) ); // 3
console.log( fSumAllDigits('123') ); // 6
console.log( fSumAllDigits(700000001) ); // 8
```

Comment: `[...''+n]` :) `acc+ +el` :))

Comment: @entithat, скорее `Array.from(n.toString).reduce...` или `n.toString().split('').reduce...` ))

Answer (score 1):

```
let x = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  x = x + Number(num[i]);
}
console.log(`Сумма всех цифр числа: ${x}`);
```

Comment: Почему не ```x += Number(num[i])```?

Comment: @OliverPatterson "Потому что потому." Владимир Путин